# How can I call functions using onkeypress-events in EJS file?

Tags: javascript, ejs, live, onkeypress

I'm trying to accomplish a live character counter for a text input field, but cannot seem to make it work. The onkeypress-function either go as undefined or is just called once when loading the page

Simply assigning the function with **onkeypress=" "** does not seem to work.

Additionally, I want to update the text of charcountLabel; which I cannot seem to do. Simply using '**document.getElementById**' for updating its innerHTML does not work.

1. *How do I correctly assign keypress-functions to html-elements in .ejs?*
2. *How do I access and update innerHTML of other elements?*

See code below:

```
    <input type="text" id="textContent" onkeypress="charcount">

    // Should be live-updated with the length of input text above.
    <span id="charcountLabel"> 0 </span> 

    <script>    
        function charcount() {
            var characterCount = document.getElementById("textContent").innerText.length;
            document.getElementById("charcountLabel").innerHTML = characterCount;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
<input type="text" id="textContent" onkeypress="charcount()">

<!-- Should be live-updated with the length of input text above. -->
<span id="charcountLabel">0</span> 
<script>
    function charcount() {
        var characterCount = document.getElementById("textContent").value.length;
        document.getElementById("charcountLabel").innerHTML = characterCount;
    }
</script>
```

Use parenthesis `()` to call the function and replace `innerText` with `value` property.
Note that `//` is comment in Javascript, not in html where you should use 
 `<!--  your comment -->` instead.
Last, it has nothing to do with ejs.